# Creating RESTful API by using pure CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I need to create a RESTful web api using only CodeIgniter. I can not use any third-party plugins or libraries to do this. I have seen that most people are using https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver. Please guide me on writing a REST api only using CodeIgniter. Helpful links and steps are highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Kisaragi Check Step 1 : "Firstly you need to download the codeigniter-restserver code from GitHub" :(

Comment: Yes, a few new classes added to your CI app. There's nothing 'outside' of codeigniter in there. Either write the exact same thing yourself, or include the library.

Comment: This is a stand alone tutorial http://outergalactic.org/blog/building-a-restful-service-using-codeigniter/

Comment: Follow [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814), but notice that it is made with CI 2. So you need to consider differences between CI v2 and CI v3 (i.e. certain filenames ucfirst, etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your are using version 3, you can do this

create a controller users.php

```
class Users extends CI_Controller {

    /**
    * @route http://proyect/users
    * @verb GET
    */
    public function get()
    {
        echo "Get";
    }

    /**
    * @route http://proyect/users
    * @verb POST
    */
    public function store()
    {
        echo "Add";
    }

    /**
    * @route http://proyect/users
    * @verb PUT
    */
    public function update()
    {
        echo "Update";
    }

    /**
    * @route http://proyect/users
    * @verb DELETE
    */
    public function delete()
    {
        echo "Delete";
    }

}
```

edit (add) in your application/config/route.php

```
$route["users"]["get"]    = "users/get";
$route["users"]["post"]   = "users/store";
$route["users"]["update"] = "users/update";
$route["users"]["delete"] = "users/delete";

$route['products/([a-zA-Z]+)/edit/(\d+)'] = function ($product_type, $id)
{
        return 'catalog/product_edit/' . strtolower($product_type) . '/' . $id;
};
```

Comment: application/config/config.php or application/config/routes.php It should be routes.php

Comment: sorry, is in `application/config/routes.php`. Can you sendme the error above, please

Comment: This is working, but the problem is, even though we have define the HTTP verb here as like get , post and etc, every url work for every request. That mean users/store url is working for all http methods (GET , POST , PUT , ....)