# Routing REST Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am creating a REST server and would like to create a url like so

```
DELETE /companies/3/employees/45
```

The endpoint should delete employee 45, which belongs to company 3.

How exactly would i go about creating a above URL using codeigniter.

Comment: I actually haven't cause i did't know where to start, i have tried endpoint liked /companies/3 or /companies/abc/3 which is simple but with /companies/3/employees/45 i don't know where to start writing my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

In your `routes.php` add a new route:

```
 $route['companies/(:num)/employees/(:num)'] = 'companies/employees/$1/$2';
```

Where `companies` is the `controller` and `employees` is the `action`.

and in your `controller`, write action something like:

```
//Use some kind of input validations for the Ids
public function employees($companyId = 0, $employeeId = 0)
{
    if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'delete')
    {
        //delete query here
    }
}
```

This uses CI routing to get params, and uses superglobal `$_SERVER` to determine whether the Request Method being used for the call is `DELETE`.

Comment: It was not necessary to add the if clause as the http verb routing is possible in the routes.php class itself and can be done as specified by @elddenmedio.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to make a rest app [like this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029421/creating-restful-api-by-using-pure-codeigniter/37036175#37036175)

Then you can make a route like

```
$route["companies"]["delete"]   = 'company/delete';
```

In your controller company

```
function delete ( ) {
    foreach($this->input->post() as $item => $value){
        ${$item} = $value;//making variables $employee_id, $company_id
    }
    //logic to delete
}
```

You need to send that info by post or make almost the same sending it to get

Comment: You are right but i have to give @mega6382 the points since that anwer came first.